# replace Dynamic string template variable with json object

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am having sample template like below i want to replace school, babydet.name,dept,babydet.section.secname with json object values how to do this please help me to solve this.

```
var Template1 = 'Welcome to the {{school}} baby {{babydet.name}}'
var Template2 = 'Welcome to the school {{school}} department {{dept}} babydetails {{babydet.name}} {{babydet.section.secname}}'

const namelist1= [{school:'GOVSchool',babydet: { name: 'shanker' }}];
const namelist2= [{school:'GOVSchool',dept:'CS',babydet: { name: 'shanker',section:{sectname:'A Section'}}}];
```

with help of string replace need to achieve this(single logic). Output want like this "Welcome to the world baby shanker"

Comment: JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON. Those are just objects.

Answer (score 4):

If by any chance that lodash.js is available, you can use the `_.template` function for it. More details [here](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#template).

```js
var Template1 = 'Welcome to the {{school}} baby {{babydet.name}}'
var Template2 = 'Welcome to the school {{school}} department {{dept}} babydetails {{babydet.name}} {{babydet.section.secname}}'

var namelist1= [{school:'GOVSchool',babydet: { name: 'shanker' }}];
var namelist2= [{school:'GOVSchool',dept:'CS',babydet: { name: 'shanker',section:{sectname:'A Section'}}}];

_.templateSettings.interpolate = /{{([\s\S]+?)}}/g;
var interpolator = _.template(Template1);
var interpolated = interpolator(namelist2[0]);

console.log(interpolated)

interpolator = _.template(Template2);
interpolated = interpolator(namelist2[0]);

console.log(interpolated)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Please keep in mind that `_.template` also allows to evaluate JavaScript code which could introduce severe security risk for unescaped input.  [See possible issue](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/5261)

Answer (score 0):

You could potentially use ES6 [Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to interpolate your strings. I'm going to make some basic assumptions (and hard-code them for this example) in order to only answer the question you asked: your `namelist` vars are stand-ins for some object parsed from JSON data, you know its structure, and you know how to iterate over a data array to make this solution real world useful.

Template literals are enclosed with backticks "`" instead of quotes, and you surround your variables with `${/* reference variable */}`

```
const namelist1= [{school:'GOVSchool',babydet: { name: 'shanker' }}];
const namelist2= [{school:'GOVSchool',dept:'CS',babydet: { name: 'shanker',section:{sectname:'A Section'}}}];

let Template1 = `Welcome to the ${namelist1[0].school} baby ${namelist1[0].babydet.name}`;
let Template2 = `Welcome to the school ${namelist2[0].school} department ${namelist2[0].dept} babydetails ${namelist2[0].babydet.name} ${namelist2[0].babydet.section.sectname}`;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can this library for string interpolation. https://www.npmjs.com/package/string-format.String::format is a small JavaScript library for formatting strings, based on Python's str.format().

Answer (score 0):

I was doing something similar, the only difference is that my JSON object would not have nested properties.

I am using a simple approach (hopefully not too simplistic). It can accept any number of properties to be substituted in the HTML template.

Given a template:

```
let template =
  '<div><span>{{ text }}</span><span>{{description}}</span></div>';
```

And some data:

```
let data = { text: 'My Text', description: 'my description' };
```

I would get:

```
<div><span>My Text</span><span>my description</span></div>
```

See the implementation in JSBin here: https://jsbin.com/zelogof/7/edit?js,console

Better suggestions also welcome!